# Direct Airside Transit Visa or Schengen visa first?

Tags: visas, schengen, transit, uk, datv

I am a Sri Lankan who lives in Hong Kong. I am travelling to France via UK. I have an air side transit. So DATV is required. But my problem is which one should be obtained first. 
Schengen visa or DAT visa.

DAT visa required to Schengen visa process

or

Schengen visa required to DTA visa process

Comment: Thank you very much. Once I try to submit Schengen visa, they asked me to get the transits visa first &come back to them, until then they can't proceed like that. But when I try to submit DAT visa, they ask me to get the destination visa (Schengen visa) first & come back to them, until then they can't proceed like that. None of them accepted the application. That's why I wanted to clarify. Thank you very much. I am now empty mind..

Comment: I have seen this type of deadlock situations in a slightly different context, every authorities set their rules independently and there is nobody to coordinate all this and guarantee that there is a reasonable or even a feasible path to get what you need. The only thing I can think of is to insist and apply for the Schengen visa again explaining as clearly as possible why you don't have a DATV yet. Alternatively, you could find another route. I don't know if it's possible for you financially but there are direct flights from Hong Kong to the Schengen area.

Comment: Yeah agreed.. Better to change the air line. otherwise this is a pain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you for the all guidance.

I just want to share the real experience I had because I assume this will be helpful when someone needs it.

On the first day I go for the Schengen visa, they requested DATV first. The next day I go for the DAT visa, they requested Schengen visa first. Then after few day I go for the Schengen visa again after explaining. They were very kind to understand my situation.

They accepted and I could get the Schengen visa after 10 days. Then I have applied for the DAT visa and I could get the visa after 8 working days.

So thank you very much to both consulates.

For the entire process it tooks around 7 weeks for me.

Comment: Thanks for coming back and updating with what happened! Hope to see you around more.

Answer (score 3):

**Schengen**, for two reasons:

1. You should have a valid visa for your destination to complete Part 8 of your [DATV application](http://www.ukba.homeoffice.gov.uk/sitecontent/applicationforms/visas/vaf6.pdf).
2. If your Schengen visa is rejected, there is no point in applying for a UK DATV.

The [UKBA site says](http://www.ukba.homeoffice.gov.uk/countries/hong-kong/processing-times/?langname=UK%20English) that 100% (!) of transit visa applications in Hong Kong are processed within 5 days, so timewise it should be no problem to apply for DATV after getting your Schengen visa.