# Do Indians require Mexico transit visa for connecting flights in Mexico city?

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens, transit-visas, mexico

I'm an Indian citizen traveling to Guatemala via New Delhi->London->Mexico City->Guatemala City. I'll require a Schengen visa to enter into Guatemala. But to travel through Mexico city do I require any Mexican visa?

Comment: *"I'll require a Schengen visa to enter into Guatemala"* uh what ?

Comment: @blackbird [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Guatemala) says holders of Schengen visas are visa exempt in Guatemala, so the sentence is probably just poorly worded. OP do you already have a valid Schengen visa (possibly from some other trip) that you intend to use?

Comment: I dont have Schengen visa but as per as embassy rules of Guatemala, An India person with B1 US, Schengen  or Canadian B1 have visa exempt in Guatemala. And from India there are no direct flights to Guatemala. 90 % flights are via US and I dont have B1 US visa. Thus routes are: India-> Amsterdam/London/Frankfurt/Madrid-> Panama City/Mexixo city-> Guatemala or India-> Canada-> Mexico/Brazil-> Guatemala ...Another problem is if I get a schengen visa it will be always single entry for first timers. So I'm deadlocked

Comment: @VenkateshMundada [You don't need](http://www.vfsglobal.com/netherlands/india/airport_transit.html) a transit visa for Schengen, as long as your luggage is checked through. It would probably be much easier to just get a visa for Guatemala.

Comment: @VenkateshMundada If your main goal is to go to Guatemala, the logical thing to do is to get a visa for Guatemala. You won't get a Schengen visa without an actual reason to go to the Schengen area (i.e. a credible plan for a visit in Europe).

Comment: @Relaxed, again If I'm applying for Guatemala visa, the visa officials may ask me the travel route and if the travel is via Europe then I require a schnegan visa beforehand. And they might reject it. I'm confused.

Comment: @VenkateshMundada What makes you think that? Have you been told you should apply for a Schengen visa by Guatemala officials? Depending on the route, you don't necessarily need a Schengen visa or perhaps only an airport transit visa. Either way, you can't claim you would be visiting the Schengen area and get a visa on that basis. So usually, you should first secure any visa you need at your destination before looking at transit visas.

Comment: You can also have a look at http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/23936/direct-airside-transit-visa-or-schengen-visa-first for a similar situation in Europe. Initially both consulates refused but explaining the problem led to a solution. Ultimately, the person had to get the visa for their final destination first and reapply for the transit visa. Insisting with Guatemala is not a perfect solution but at least it seems more likely to succeed than going for a Schengen visa without a good premise.

Comment: Thanks @Relaxed, last time I was refused for US C1 transit visa, as I lacked Guatemalan visa. I initially preferred the US travel route option (India-US-Guatemala)

Comment: @VenkateshMundada Yes, that's pretty much what I would expect and fits my earlier comments. You should start with Guatemala (your actual destination and the reason why you are doing this trip) and then work from there. As far as the US or EU countries are concerned, you don't need a visa if you are not going to Guatemala so you must show them the Guatemalan visa to establish why you need to transit.

Answer (score 5):

> As of February 17, 2004 foreigners passing through one of Mexico’s
>   international airports to a third country no longer require a visa or
>   any migratory documentation, provided that they remain at the airport
>   and depart Mexico within 24 hours of arrival. <sup>[Source](http://www.mexperience.com/lifestyle/mexico-essentials/mexico-entry-requirements/)</sup>

However, it may only work if your luggage is checked automatically through, so that you don't need to collect it and check it in again. (You're sometimes going to be unable to do that without a visa.)

It's not a reliable source, but this post [claims there is no transit area](https://insideflyer.com/forums/threads/beware-of-transit-through-mexico-city.20192/) in Mexico City International Airport. So I would advise you to check this carefully with the airline and Mexican Embassy. You might need a transit visa.

Comment: As inquired from embassy of Mexico in India on phone, it says a visa is must

Comment: @VenkateshMundada Thanks for letting me know. Please post this as an answer, not just a comment.

Comment: @VenkateshMundada Are you sure you made it perfectly clear to them that you were talking about transit only?

Comment: Yes, like your point is valid if there's a single ticket from source to destination place. But these things have to be confirmed with airlines. Example my friend went to Uruguay via Brazil from India and throughout it was a single ticket and thus he didn't apply for a transit Brazil visa

Comment: @VenkateshMundada Yes, like I said in the answer, it often only works if it's a single booking and your luggage is checked through. And yeah, it's always good to check with the airline and embassies. I also found some other additional information which I have added to the answer. You want to check this carefully.